# PHP function property call count?

Tags: php, function, variables

I am calling this function multiple times, passing extra parameter of $case which tells me how many time this function is called:

```
function check($chars,$case=1){
    $charNums = array(
        "a" => "2",
        "b" => "22",
        "c" => "222",
        "d" => "3",
        "e" => "33",
        "f" => "333",
        "g" => "4",
        "h" => "44",
        "i" => "444",
        "j" => "5",
        "k" => "55",
        "l" => "555",
        "m" => "6",
        "n" => "66",
        "o" => "666",
        "p" => "7",
        "q" => "77",
        "r" => "777",
        "s" => "7777",
        "t" => "8",
        "u" => "88",
        "v" => "888",
        "w" => "9",
        "x" => "99",
        "y" => "999",
        "z" => "9999",
        " " => "0",
    );
    echo "Case #{$case}: ";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($chars);$i++){
        if($prevChar == $charNums[$chars[$i]][0]) echo " ";
        echo $charNums[$chars[$i]];
        $prevChar = $charNums[$chars[$i]][0];
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I want this function to count itself how many times it is called. To save the extra parameter cost, I have seen that each javascript function have its own default attributes.

Comment: how is the value of $cost changing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a static variable:

```
function check($chars){
  static $count = 0;
  ++$count;

  // TODO: your implementation here

  return $count;
}
```

If you already use the return value for some other purpose, you can wrap the function in a class:

```
class Checker {
  public static $count = 0;
  public static function check($chars) {
    ++self::$count;

    // TODO: your implementation here

    return $whatever;
  }
}
```

Comment: He is saying that he dont want any extra parameter.. But this seems to be using the same parameter which he want to remove or replace with some alternative...

Comment: There is no extra parameter. In fact, the one that was used for counting is removed.

Comment: You are right... Seems to be a solution.. Wasn't looking at the definition properly.. solved my doubt too.. thnx

Comment: Is there any default php function like:
func_num_calls()

Answer (score 0):

You did not declear

> $prevChar

for matching in for loop...

### if($prevChar == $charNums[$chars[$i]][0]) echo " ";

Use this

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($chars);$i++){
        $prevChar = $chars[$i];
        if($prevChar == $charNums[$chars[$i]][0]) echo " ";
        echo $charNums[$chars[$i]];
        $prevChar = $charNums[$chars[$i]][0];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas for pointing out, but I need help on function internal call count

Comment: i use for($k=0; $k<10; $k++){ check("aaabbcccdz",$k); } 
it give me case. for how many time this function call.